# filter sharepoint list and send all matching rows in email in PowerApp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I have a sharepoint list of clients and list of tasks for each client with start date, end date, and status.

I have a filter and a gallery that shows filtered data based on the dropdown selected value (client).

I want to get tasks for the selected client using a dropdown and send the tasks list in an email in the table format.

For example, if client A is selected from the drop down, and send email button is selected, an email should be sent.

Table format is

**Client       Task        StartDate     EndDate    Status**

A            meeting       1-1-2023      1-2-2023   Complete

A            Final plan    1-3-2023      1-5-2023  In Progress

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.
We can do it by creating an HTML table of all items in the filtered Gallery and send this HTML table in the email